# Extract a city (specific word) from a column in a data frame in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have an excel file and I've read it as a data frame and loaded to R.
One of the columns is a text column containing one or more words. I have to find whether a cell contains a specific city provided in the "City_Vector" (e.g. `c("New York", "Beijing", "Paris", "London")` and extract it (or extract the first match/all matches).
In Excel I used a user-defined function and got smth like that:

`| For Moscow State University |` should return `Moscow`;
`| asdsadsadsaWarsawsdaqq |` should return `Warsaw`

I tried to split up the string and use `%in%` but it doesn't seem to be the best solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aim is to extract matches irrespective of case then this should work:

Data:

```
City_Vector <- c("New York", "Bejing", "Paris", "London", "Moscow", "Warsaw")
cities <- c('Moscow State University','asdsadsadsaWarsawsdaqq', 
            'New York Philhamonics', 'food in Bejing', 'parisclimateaccord')
```

Solution:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(cities, paste0("(?i)(", paste0(City_Vector, collapse = "|"), ")"))
```

Explanation:

The point here is to formulate all the possible city names as a pattern of alternatives (note the alternation marker `|`) using nested `paste0` commands.

**EDIT**:

`(?i)`is used to make the pattern case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks! But what about to make it not case-sensitive? Or it's only possible when we add to the city vector both `Warsaw` and `warsaw`?

Comment: Or just use `tolower()` and work with lower case strings

Comment: Have edited the answer to make the pattern case-insensitive. Please consider accepting and/or upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_extract()` from the `stringr` package.

Overly simple example:

```
cityVec <- c('Moscow State University','asdsadsadsaWarsawsdaqq')
str_extract(cityVec, 'Moscow')
```

Comment: This only checks if there is a match for `Moscow` but not for any other city name